# Expand the container to fill the remaining space but must fill the min height when shrink

Tags: flutter, dart

There is a listview and a widget below listview in Column widget. I want to expand the widget below list as max as possible to fill the available space. When I start populating the list with items I want to make the list area expand as with entries and shrink the widget below listview but not less than the min possible height.

This is my code.

```html
Column
(
children: [
Container(

            child: cartList.isNotEmpty
                ? RawScrollbar(
                    thumbColor: Colors.grey[200],
                    isAlwaysShown: true,
                    controller: controller,
                    thickness: 12,
                    radius: const Radius.circular(20),
                    child: ListView.separated(
                      itemCount: cartList.length,
                      controller: controller,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return const SizedBox(
                          height: 4,
                        );
                      },
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 12, bottom: 10),
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return SingleCartWidget(
                          resetSelection: () {
                            resetSelection(index);
                          },
                          cartItem: cartList[index],
                          fontSize: textSize,
                          removeItem: () {
                            if (cartList.length == 1 &&
                                HotKeysWidget.of(context)!.orderType ==
                                    'unpaid') {
                              HotKeysWidget.of(context)!.showAlertDialog();
                            } else {
                              if (globals.selectedItem != null) {
                                if (globals.selectedItem.id ==
                                    cartList[index].id) {
                                  widget.resetSelection(null);
                                }
                              }
                              HotKeysWidget.of(context)!
                                  .removeCartItem(cartList[index]);
                            }
                          },
                          orderType: HotKeysWidget.of(context)!.getOrderType(),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                : const Text(
                    'Cart list is empty',
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 14,
                    ),
                  ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.05,
              ),
              child: Listener(
                onPointerDown: (e) async {
                  print('AREA TAPPED#####################33');
                  setState(() {
                    cartList.forEach((element) {
                      if (element.selected) element.selected = false;
                    });
                  });
                  globals.selectedItem = null;
                  widget.resetSelection(null);
                },
                child: Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          ]
)
```

The issue I am facing right now is that the list expand to max and the widget below listview become shrink to invisible.
How can I achieve this. Can anyone help me.

Comment: can you try  **ConstrainedBox** with `minHeight` & `maxHeight`  ?

Comment: Same result with ConstrainedBox also